# Need to get data from dictionaries into pandas, but the dict keys change

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have thousands of dictionaries that I need to put into a single pandas data frame. The dictionaries look like this:

```
{'screen_width': 375,
 'city': 'London',
 'source': 'Mobile',
 'appVersion': '5.3.0',
 'connectionType': 'wifi',
 'sheetName': 'Regional Asset',
 '$device': 'iPhone',
 '$user_id': 'name@email.com',
 '$device_id': '172fe47',
 '$os': 'iOS',
 '$manufacturer': 'Apple',
 '$os_version': '13.4.1',
 '$lib_version': '1.3.0',
 'distinct_id': 'name@email.com',
 'fieldName': 'barcode',
 '$screen_height': 812,
 'mp_country_code': 'UK',
 '$model': 'iPhone12,3',
 'time': 1593404157
}
```

The problem I am having is that with each dictionary there might be an entry (such as city) missing from the dictionary, in which case the key isn't there either. This is causing me massive problems.

What I've tried so far:

```
file = ('{0}.csv'.format(file_name))
    df = pd.read_json(file)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = [Column_names])
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
            df1.loc[i] = [df.iloc[i,0]] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$screen_width']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$city']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['source']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['connectionType']] \
            + [df.iloc[i,1]['sheetName']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$device']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$user_id']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$device_id']] \
            + [df.iloc[i,1]['$os']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['mp_country_code']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$manufacturer']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$os_version']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$lib_version']] \
            + [df.iloc[i,1]['distinct_id']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$screen_height']]+ [df.iloc[i,1]['$model']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$region']] \
            + [df.iloc[i,1]['mp_lib']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['time']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['mp_processing_time_ms']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$browser']] + [df.iloc[i,1]['$insert_id']]
```

But as soon as it comes across a dictionary with city missing I get

```
KeyError: '$city'
```

I've also tried to add

```
try:
   enter code here
except (KeyError):
    pass
```

But that just returns an empty data frame.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: use collection defaultdict for the mising values

Answer (score 0):

````py
import pandas as pd

    
my_dict  ={'screen_width': 375,
 'city': 'London',
 'source': 'Mobile',
 'appVersion': '5.3.0',
 'connectionType': 'wifi',
 'sheetName': 'Regional Asset',
 '$device': 'iPhone',
 '$user_id': 'name@email.com',
 '$device_id': '172fe47',
 '$os': 'iOS',
 '$manufacturer': 'Apple',
 '$os_version': '13.4.1',
 '$lib_version': '1.3.0',
 'distinct_id': 'name@email.com',
 'fieldName': 'barcode',
 '$screen_height': 812,
 'mp_country_code': 'UK',
 '$model': 'iPhone12,3',
 'time': 1593404157
}

my_dict_2 = {'screen_width': 375,
 'source': 'Mobile',
 'appVersion': '5.3.0',
 'connectionType': 'wifi',
 'sheetName': 'Regional Asset',
 '$device': 'iPhone',
 '$user_id': 'name@email.com',
 '$device_id': '172fe47',
 '$os': 'iOS',
 '$manufacturer': 'Apple',
 '$os_version': '13.4.1',
 '$lib_version': '1.3.0',
 'distinct_id': 'name@email.com',
 'fieldName': 'barcode',
 '$screen_height': 812,
 'mp_country_code': 'UK',
 '$model': 'iPhone12,3',
 'time': 1593404157}

my_dict_3 = {'screen_width': 375,
 'city': 'London',
 'source': 'Mobile',
 'appVersion': '5.3.0',
 'connectionType': 'wifi',
 '$device': 'iPhone',
 '$user_id': 'name@email.com',
 '$device_id': '172fe47',
 '$os': 'iOS',
 '$manufacturer': 'Apple',
 '$os_version': '13.4.1',
 '$lib_version': '1.3.0',
 'distinct_id': 'name@email.com',
 'fieldName': 'barcode',
 '$screen_height': 812,
 'mp_country_code': 'UK',
 '$model': 'iPhone12,3',
 'time': 1593404157}

list_of_dictionaries = [my_dict, my_dict_2, my_dict_3]

start = True


for my_dict in list_of_dictionaries:
    if start:
        my_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([my_dict])
        start = False
    else:
        my_df = pd.concat([my_df, pd.DataFrame.from_dict([my_dict])])```
````

Comment: Hi there, the three dictionaries I have used as an example have different missing key:value pairs. I loop through them, convert into a dataframe then concatenate into the dataframe. Any missing values turn up as NA in the final dataframe

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for your time in answering this question. You can edit your answer any time. You don't have to use the comment function to add information.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If your first dictionary doesn't have all the columns, the missed columns align at the end. So it is good to define all possible columns first.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the possible columns that exists in your json file, you can define a dataFrame with all possible columns, and then load each dictionary into your dataFrame.
The file sample.txt contains list of dictinories

```
[
{"col1": "10",
 "col2": "London",
 "col3": "Mobile",
 "col4": "Mobile"},
 {"col1": "20",
 "col2": "TOKYO",
 "col4": "Mobile",
 "col5": "Mobile"},
 {"col1": "30",
 "col2": "NewYork",
 "col3": "Mobile",
 "col4": "Mobile",
 "col5": "Mobile"}
 ]
```

Program:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result= pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4','col5'])
    f= open('sample.txt', 'r')
    raw_data = json.loads(f.read())
    for i in raw_data:
        result = result.append(i, ignore_index=True)
        print(i)
    print(result)
```

The output of the program is:

```
  col1     col2    col3    col4    col5
0   10   London  Mobile  Mobile     NaN
1   20    TOKYO     NaN  Mobile  Mobile
2   30  NewYork  Mobile  Mobile  Mobile
```

Answer (score 0):

@Venkat J provided the list of dictionaries.  You can pass this directly to the DataFrame constructor.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"col1": "10",
     "col2": "London",
     "col3": "Mobile",
     "col4": "Mobile"},
     {"col1": "20",
     "col2": "TOKYO",
     "col4": "Mobile",
     "col5": "Mobile"},
     {"col1": "30",
     "col2": "NewYork",
     "col3": "Mobile",
     "col4": "Mobile",
     "col5": "Mobile"}
]

pd.DataFrame(data)
```